# Cannot Start Tor

Tags: bridge

Tried to set up latest Tor with bridges. Obtained three bridges from the tor-bridges site. Input those into the empty box under Custom Bridges. Ran through other settings when Tor was up and functional. Selected "Use hardware acceleration when available" When I restarted Tor, it could never start, had an APPCRASh and would shut down. Went back and unselected the hardware acceleration....that allowed the Tor browser to start, but the onion has a red x on it. Copied this from the start up:

```
6/6/2016 9:59:17 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
6/6/2016 9:59:17 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
6/6/2016 9:59:17 AM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.36.31.117:54458 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host 895736BD379E216C789E2EB96914A1BDDFAB0E31 at 194.132.209.225:56635) 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.400 [WARN] 2 connections have failed: 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.500 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
6/6/2016 9:59:18 AM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: On windows 7 64 bit

Comment: We're seeing a 1 second snapshot of the logs during startup, could we see a full log of it trying to start up? Also could you *redact* the bridge IP addresses? They're intended to be unpublished. If you had a reason to use bridges you just told people what those IP address and port combinations are...do you need bridges to connect to the tor network?